# QT Editor smart buttons

Tags: c++, qt

I have a toolbar with buttons: undo, redo, cut, copy, paste, like below:

```
editmenu = menuBar()->addMenu(QObject::tr("&Edit"));
undoact = editmenu->addAction(QIcon(":images/undo.png"), QObject::tr("&Undo"));
QObject::connect(editwin, SIGNAL(undoAvailable(bool)), undoact, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
QObject::connect(undoact, SIGNAL(triggered()), editwin, SLOT(undo()));
undoact->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::keyBindings(QKeySequence::Undo));
undoact->setEnabled(false);
redoact = editmenu->addAction(QIcon(":images/redo.png"), QObject::tr("&Redo"));
QObject::connect(editwin, SIGNAL(redoAvailable(bool)), redoact, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
QObject::connect(redoact, SIGNAL(triggered()), editwin, SLOT(redo()));
redoact->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::keyBindings(QKeySequence::Redo));
redoact->setEnabled(false);
editmenu->addSeparator();
cutact = editmenu->addAction(QIcon(":images/cut.png"), QObject::tr("Cu&t"));
cutact->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::keyBindings(QKeySequence::Cut));
cutact->setEnabled(false);
copyact = editmenu->addAction(QIcon(":images/copy.png"), QObject::tr("&Copy"));
copyact->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::keyBindings(QKeySequence::Copy));
copyact->setEnabled(false);
pasteact = editmenu->addAction(QIcon(":images/paste.png"), QObject::tr("&Paste"));
pasteact->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::keyBindings(QKeySequence::Paste));
```

I want:

1. Paste button to be enabled only if clipboard contain text
2. For some reason, I need to disable all buttons for a limitted period of time. After this I want to enable all buttons. But when I enable, each button to be enabled/disabled according to his condition (eg. undo button to be enabled only if there is something to undo, paste button to be enabled only if there is some text that can be pasted ...)

What do you advise me to do? What is the smartest / simplest method?

Answer (score 2):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#signals

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#details

Create connections from the `QClipboard` object to a handler slots in your toolbar/mainwindow class.  And then in the handler slot do the logic you want to happen to your toolbar buttons.

For example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#dataChanged

```
// in your constructor after creating your buttons:
QObject::connect(qApp->clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()), 
    this, SLOT(onClipboardDataChanged()));

// and then make another connection for the other relevant clipboard signal...
// selectionChanged()
```

Then later in in your slot:

```
void MainWindow::onClipboardDataChanged()
{
     const QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
     const QMimeData *mimeData = clipboard->mimeData();

     pasteact->setEnabled(mimeData->hasText());
     // or you could check the length of the text to see if it is non zero.
}
```

To disable/renable all the buttons at once, disable the parent object instead.

```
editToolbar->setEnabled(false);
//... after some period of time or transactions...
editToolbar->setEnabled(true);
```

But this probably won't disable the built-in accelerators for Copy, Cut and Paste.  To kill those keyboard shortcuts, too, you may need to put an event filter on your app.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/accelerators.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Hope that helps.

PS.  I haven't tested this chunk of code.  Read the docs.  Good luck.